# lucene4.5 deleteDocument and updateDocument is not working

Tags: java, lucene

```
Directory indexDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File("D:" + File.separator + "testindex"));

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_45);

IndexWriterConfig writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_45, analyzer);

writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig);

Document document = new Document();

Field stringField = new TextField("int1", "hello lucky boy", Store.YES);


document.add(stringField);

indexWriter.addDocument(document);

indexWriter.close();

Term term = new Term("int1", "hello lucky boy");

IndexWriterConfig writerConfig2 = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_45, analyzer);

IndexWriter indexWriter2 = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig2);
indexWriter2.updateDocument(term, document);

indexWriter2.deleteDocuments(term);

indexWriter2.close();
System.out.println("......" + document);

System.out.println("...跟新索引文件结束...");
```

the  updateDocument or deleteDocuments is not working.

The document is still the same. My lucene is the 4.5.
Is anything wrong?

I have searched many methods. It looks like the same, so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1 - This:

```
Term term = new Term("int1", "hello lucky boy");
```

Will not be analyzed.  Since you are indexing documents with StandardAnalyzer, you would expect to find the terms:  'hello', 'lucky', and 'boy' in the index.  Your query is for the single term 'hello lucky boy', and so you will find no matches.  When updating or deleting documents, using a `Term` to identify them, it is assumed you can uniquely identify documents with a single term.  If you can't do that, pass in a query instead, then you can rely on the QueryParser to apply analysis for you.

A good demonstration of this: search for your term with a `TermQuery`

```
TopDocs docs = indexSearcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("int1", "hello lucky boy")), 10);
```

If you get no results, then neither will lucene when it tries to find documents to delete.

2 - This:

```
indexWriter2.updateDocument(term, document);

indexWriter2.deleteDocuments(term);
```

There is no need to delete documents after you have just got done updating them.  The old documents were already deleted by the `updateDocuments` call.  If you changed the content such that `term` will no longer match the updated document, it does nothing.  If `term` does still match, it will delete the new version of the document.

3 - You don't show how you are viewing the index, but make sure you reopen the reader after updating the index.  If you don't, you won't see changes to documents until you do.

Comment: I can answer the 3 question.I view the docuemnt in the debug model,it is the same.I have taken your first opinion,however not work.